# How to COPY or ADD multiple files and directories in one layer with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to ADD/COPY files and directories in one layer with Dockerfile like this:

```
ADD file.txt dir1 /app/
```

But it is only copying the content of `dir1` instead of the dir itself, how can I copy/add the files and directories in one layer?

Comment: Does the number of layers make any difference to your application at all; is there any reason two layers is different from one?  If you use the [newer BuildKit engine](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) (which may be enabled by default for your), and you look at the `docker history` of the built images, are the adjacent `COPY` lines combined into a single layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs on [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) clearly note, that only the content of the directory is copied but not the directory itself.

So for this to work you could create a subdirectory `foo` containing `file.txt` and `dir1` and then do

```
ADD foo /app/
```

which would copy the content of the `foo` directory into your image.